# Gdiplus not working, error "PROPID has not been declared"

Tags: c++, gdi+

I'm a beginner when it comes to C++. I'm trying to use GDI+ and I'm following this tutorial from Microsoft: [Drawing a Line](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdiplus/-gdiplus-drawing-a-line-use)

I'm building the app with the following commands, but all with the same result:

```bash
g++ main.cpp window.cpp -o app.exe
g++ main.cpp window.cpp -libgdiplus -o app.exe
g++ main.cpp window.cpp -libgdiplus -lgdi32 -o app.exe
```

It gives me a lot of errors inside of `gdiplusimpl.h`, almost all of which are referring to `PROPID` not being declared or not naming a type.

This is the way I refer to the library in my cpp files:

```cpp
#include <gdiplus.h>

using namespace Gdiplus;
#pragma comment (lib, "Gdiplus.lib")
```

What can I do to be able to build the app?

Comment: Put `#include <windows.h>` before `#include <gdiplus.h>`  Note the linked tutorial has headers you are not including, why did you miss them out ?

Comment: I'm not just copy-pasting the code, but I indeed missed "objidl". My code is currently on 3 files, and I'm not able to paste it here completely. However, after adding that other import, now i have a different error, I'm updating my question reflecting this.

Comment: Ended up fixing this, I missed an import and used the wrong flag. I'll post an answer instead of editing the question

Answer (score 0):

While following the tutorial, I missed an import (`objidl.h`). After adding it in the proper place, Almost all errors went away. It still didn't compile though, and was giving errors about undefined GDI+ functions. However, that was because I was using the wrong command. By running this command it compiled correctly:

```bash
g++ main.cpp window.cpp -lgdiplus -o app.exe
```

The difference was a simple typo: `lgdiplus` instead of `libgdiplus`.